# Can I make fn + caps lock enable caps lock when caps lock is mapped to control?

Tags: keyboard, caps-lock

I know that I can [remap caps lock to control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15462034/1054633). However, I occasionally wish that I still had a way to use caps lock.

After mapping caps lock to control, is there a way to temporarily reenable caps lock (perhaps via <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>caps lock</kbd>)? I would prefer to *not* have to map a different modifier key to caps lock.

Comment: I'm remapping to escape and I have the same question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) has some [complex modifications](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/) that allow toggling caps lock without using the caps lock key:

- Toggle caps_lock by pressing left_shift + right_shift at the same time
- Post caps_lock if escape is pressed alone
- Change left_shift to caps_lock if alone
- Change right_shift to caps_lock if pressed alone